# Accumulation Values of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$a_n=(1+ \frac{1}{n})^ {-4+n}$

How do you find all the accumulation points of a sequence?
I normally firstly look of the first  members of the sequence and try to find a subsequences. Then calculate their limit and then I have the accumulation points.

I know that the sequence is increasing and that the limit of $a_n= e $. But I could not get further.
Could you give me any tips for the problem and in general, how you proceed? And maybe is a stupid question, but if you have the limit of sequence is it so that the subsequences have the same limit as the limit of the sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Accumulation points for a sequence indicates towards all subsequential limits.

Whenever a sequence converge, it have only one accumulation point.

As your example,the only accumulation value is $e$